# Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Not started Java application on Intellij Idea 2011 with Spring-boot configuration. Someone may have encountered a similar problem before. Maybe this is due to the settings, but I do not know which ones. My coding experience in Java 2 months.

Console:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-04 14:17:07.360 ERROR 8924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.simbirsoft.severstal.mvp.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration$DifferentManagementContextConfiguration
    ...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If you need to provide other files, then tell me what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Error was becouse Intellij Idea 2021.2.0 not support envfile pluggin and not support variables written in application.env. I solve this problem, i write in environment variables "Run/Debug configuration" window.

Comment: Hi @Андрей Бердников , I am getting the same exception but in docker. Can you please elaborate on your resolution and exact issue.